# Delphi - Check if a record already exists in the database

Tags: delphi, grid, firedac

I'm trying to make a comparison between the products of one cxGrid with products already registered to the base, but I have doubts.

I have the following tables:

product: id (pk), description, reference

items_note: product (pk), description, unit

Trying to do at the event cxGridProdutoCustomDrawCell, but it's not working

```
procedure TFrmCompra.cxGridProdutoCustomDrawCell(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
  ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo;
  var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if QryItemNota.fieldByName('PRODUTO').asString <> QryProduto.fieldByName('REFERENCIA').asString then
  begin
     ACanvas.Font.Color := clRed
  end
  else
     ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
end;
```

Used Delphi RIO 10.3, Firebird Database with Firedac components

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Have you set ADone to True?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is Every Cell Black is Every Cell Red or is there no change? What does the 2 Fields Respond. Are they Accessible? Do you get Errors? Please try except that block an See if you get some Errors.

Comment: I think inside of a CustomDrawCell it is your responsability to actually paint in the canvas. Not just set the color. Try using the method TextOut of canvas.

Comment: @MundoPeter:  Not with the DevExpress TcxGrid.  If you want to draw the cell entirely yourself then you do it and set ADone to True.  What the OP is doing should work fine.

Comment: I'm wandering more if used I clause even returns desired result. I mean does the above code makes comparison of string values of each field or references to string objects that store values for each field. If it is latter than the logic check of the above if clause will always return false. So it might be necessary to use [ComareStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.CompareStr) to make sure that the value of both strings that represent field values are compared.

Comment: @SilverWarior:  Sorry, I can't follow what you mean by "does the above code makes comparison of string values of each field or references to string objects that store values for each field".  The code as written clearly compares the values **as strings** of the two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pity you didn't actually say whether the text in the cell is drawn with the font set to red or to black.  It should work fine so if its only using black or red for you, your `if` test is going wrong.  First, temporarily change your code to

```
procedure TFrmCompra.cxGridProdutoCustomDrawCell(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
  ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo;
  var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  ACanvas.Font.Color := clRed
end;
```

and satisfy yourself that the text is indeed red.  Then, temporarily change your code to

```
procedure TFrmCompra.cxGridProdutoCustomDrawCell(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
  ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo;
  var ADone: Boolean);
var
  S1, 
  S2 : String;
begin
  S1 := QryItemNota.fieldByName('PRODUTO').asString;
  S2 := QryProduto.fieldByName('REFERENCIA').asString;
  if S1 <> S2 then
  begin
     ACanvas.Font.Color := clRed
  end
  else
     ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
end;
```

Then, put a breakpoint on the `if S1 <> S2 then` line and run the program until the breakpoint hits.  Use F7 to evaluate S1 and S2 and you should immediately see why you aren't getting the result you're expecting.  Most likely S1 and S2 are *always* equal or *never* equal.

Another piece of information you didn't include is which of the two queries is supplying the grid view and which is the one you are checking it against.  Unless you **know** that the other query is correctly synchronised with the displayed one, you should be doing something like

```
if QueryB.Locate({query B field name}, QueryA.FieldByName({query A field name}).AsString, []) then
   //  take record found action
else
   //  take record not found action
```

This checks whether the value from the current row in QueryA is (which is being processed in the CustomDraw event) can be found in QueryB.

Comment: My failure to create the question, some information is really missing.

But I would like to thank MartynA for the answers using Locate really finds the first line in the database but the other lines are also in black, I believe I need to go through the lines to check each one.

I need to distinguish the products that are in the database in black and those that are not in red, in order to call a form to register them.

Comment: Well, if you repeat my first suggested change `begin  ACanvas.Font.Color := clRed
end;` using black insteaad, you should be able to satisfy yourself that the text color really is determined by the code in the DrawCell event, and from there, the second change using S1 & S2 and Locate should be simple.